# Set up a TextBox that accepts only a range of times

Tags: vb.net, validation, time, textbox

I need to insert in a textbox the time intervals with the format `hh:mm/hh:mm` (e.g., `08:00/13:00`, `14:00/18:00`) to set the reception times of a specific user.

How can I do this by also entering a control on the time entered (if I enter `25:60/70:90`, it must not be accepted because the timetable does not exist). Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the input should be only a valid time value 00:00 - 23:59 and you need also to validate the inputs? (IE: Second time should be not lesser than the first time?)

Comment: @Steve "Second time should be not lesser than the first time" What if their shift spans midnight?

Comment: @Steve, thank you for the reply, for the moment I need to control only the value

Comment: You could use 4 DateTimePicker Controls (with CustomFormat `HH:mm`) and determine the `MinDate` and `MaxDate` (using only the Time) of the second couple when the Value of the first couple changes, which is notified by the ValueChanged event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use [`TimeSpan.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparseexact). This will give you the same result and it also allows you to easily get the time values as `TimeSpan`s so you can use them for further calculations or for storing them somewhere, for example.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Dim validRange As Boolean = False
    Dim time1, time2 As TimeSpan

    Dim timeRanges As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split("/"c)
    If timeRanges.Length = 2 Then
        If TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeRanges(0), "hh\:mm",
                                  Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, time1) AndAlso
           TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeRanges(1), "hh\:mm",
                                  Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, time2) Then
            validRange = True
        End If
    End If

    If validRange Then
        ' Use `time` and `time2` for anything you want.
    Else
        ' TODO: Indicate to the user that they entered an invalid input.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### Edit:

If you don't want to manually type `:` and `/`, you can use a [`MaskedTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox) instead of a TextBox.

First, after adding a MaskedTextBox onto your form, set its `Mask` property to `00:00/00:00`:

[image: MaskedTextBox.Mask]

Then you can adjust the code above to work with a MaskedTextBox like this:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.Validating
    Dim validRange As Boolean = False
    Dim time1, time2 As TimeSpan

    Dim timeRanges As String() = MaskedTextBox1.Text.Split("/"c)
    If MaskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted Then
        If TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeRanges(0), "hh\:mm",
                                  Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, time1) AndAlso
           TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeRanges(1), "hh\:mm",
                                  Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, time2) Then
            validRange = True
        End If
    End If

    If validRange Then
        ' Use `time` and `time2` for anything you want.
    Else
        ' TODO: Indicate to the user that they entered an invalid input.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) for this validation. You'd need to use a pattern like this one:

```regex
(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\/(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d
```

[**Try it online**](https://regex101.com/r/VQN9qB/1).

First, add the following reference:

```vb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then, assuming this is a WinForms project, you'll need to use the `TextBox.Validating` event like this:

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Const pattern As String = "(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\/(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d"

    If Not Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text, pattern) Then
        ' TODO: Indicate to the user that they entered an invalid input.
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried and the data validation works. How can I control the typing so that : / and - appear by themselves when I type? Example: when I type the hour I would like : to appear alone so that I can write the minutes directly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GiuliaTurco Check the "Edit" section in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315142/4934172).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will return a `List(Of TimeSpan)` if four valid times are found in the format you specified.  It's a bit clunky, by design, so you can see exactly the steps taken to ensure all the parts are valid.  Once you've got those four times back as TimeSpans, you can further process them to see if they make sense together as a "shift":

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim times As List(Of TimeSpan) = ParseShift(TextBox1.Text)
    If times.Count = 4 Then
        Label1.Text = "Valid Times Found"
        ' perform some kind of validation on them?
        For Each ts As TimeSpan In times
            Debug.Print(ts.ToString)
        Next
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Invalid Times and/or Shift Description"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ParseShift(ByVal input As String) As List(Of TimeSpan)
    Dim values() As String = input.Split("-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    If values.Length = 2 Then
        Dim firstHalf() As String = values(0).Split("/".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim secondHalf() As String = values(1).Split("/".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If firstHalf.Length = 2 AndAlso secondHalf.Length = 2 Then
            Dim strTimes As New List(Of String)
            strTimes.AddRange(firstHalf)
            strTimes.AddRange(secondHalf)
            Dim ts As TimeSpan
            Dim times As New List(Of TimeSpan)
            For Each strTime As String In strTimes
                If TimeSpan.TryParseExact(strTime.Trim, "hh\:mm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, ts) Then
                    times.Add(ts)
                End If
            Next
            If times.Count = 4 Then
                Return times
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return New List(Of TimeSpan)
End Function
```